# How to apply custom tokenizer without using regex in ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

I am using Ace editor in my text area for highlighting. I have my own tokenizer without using regex. The tokenizer is in the server side and called using http call. Now what I wanted to do is to highlight every token I got from the server. I tried to use addMarker function to highlight every token but does not work. Sample code below,

```
highlightToken = function(token) {
var
  aceRange = ace.require('ace/range').Range,
  row = editor.selection.lead.row, // editor is my ace editor
  adjAceRange = new aceRange(row, token.position - 1 , row, token.position + token.length),
  styleClass = token.type;

editor.session.addMarker(adjAceRange, styleClass, "text", true);
```

}

In my css,

```
 .styleClass { 
   position:absolute;
   color: blue;}
```

The color of the token does not change. But if I add background property in the css, the background of the token is changed. Did I miss something?